# Jquery issue with raills controller method responding to JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

There is popup box, which contains form for new User. It is submited remotely. If @user.save, I use the js file to redirect, if not - just refreshing the popup box. Refreshing works fine, but redirecting is an issue.

Here is my code:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.email=@user.email.downcase
    @user.guest=false
    if @user.save
      @status=true
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
    else
      @status=false
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{@status}
    end
  end
```

And create.js.erb:

```
if(<%=@status %>) {
    window.location.replace("<%= j root_url %>")
}else {
    $('.new_user_popup').replaceWith("<%= j render :partial => 'users/form' %>");
    $('.new_user_popup').fadeIn('fast');

}
```

And one important moment, which puzzles me really hard - **separately from else script works.**
I mean, if I remove else part, and @user.save - it redirects, as expected.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you add a semi-colon to the end of: window.location.replace("<%= j root_url %>") ?

Comment: tried... pretty the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell, what was bad with this code. Actually, pretty same logic worked fine in similary cases, I think it is connected with rails default behaviour for default methods like 'create'.
Just fixed it this way:

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.email=@user.email.downcase
    @user.guest=false
    if @user.save
      @status=true
      render :action => 'redirect_user'
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
    else
      render :action =>'reload_box'
    end
  end

  def redirect_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
  end

  def reload_box
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And each JS template works with its part of code.